# git merge does not result in conflicts or auto-merge for some files

Tags: git

so I was doing a regular `git merge --no-ff --no-commit master` on my branch, and to my surprise some files that I know differ between branches (`git diff --name-status mybranch..master`), were not listed as auto-merged nor as conflicts! After other all conflicts are resolved, I can see that affected files are still as per 'mybranch'...

I'm working on shared GitHub repo and all I know is that this branch was synced before with 'master' without problems (but never 'mybranch' into 'master'). What's going on?

How can I fix the situation, understand what really happened and avoid situations like that in future?

My git is `1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)` running on OS X 10.8.3.

**UPDATE:** doing a clean clone, results in the same issue.

Comment: After the merge does `git diff master` report anything? If not then the merge has been successful. You could also use `git show` after the merge to see what the merge did.

Comment: @cbuckley: the affected files are not listed in `git show` output, but are listed in `git diff --name-status master` as modified...

Comment: Hmm… what does `git diff mybranch...master` and `git diff master...mybranch` show for those files? Note the three dots (`a...b` means only the commits on `b` since they diverged). Maybe both branches introduce the same changes somehow?

Comment: @cbuckley: good point! Some offending files (don't know if all of them - too many files) are listed in `master...mybranch`, but not in `mybranch...master`. What does it mean now? I'm in the woods. Maybe a previous merge resolved (manually) conflicts in a way git lost track somehow?

Comment: It's difficult to give an answer without a branch visualisation. Maybe that would help you too; have a look using tig or gitk or `git log --graph`.